# Writing temp files to Heroku from an S3 hosted file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, temporary-files

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku.  Here's the situation: a user should be able to upload a PDF (an instance of Batch) to our app using s3; a user should also be able to take the s3 web address of the uploaded PDF and split it up into more PDFs using [HyPDF](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/hypdf) by specifying the file path and the desired pages to be split out (to create instances of Essay).

All of this is happening in the same POST request to `/essays`.

Here's the code I've been working with today:

```rb
 def create
    if params[:essay].class == String 
      batch_id = params[:batch_id].gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i
      break_up_batch(params, batch_id)
      redirect_to Batch.find(batch_id), notice: 'Essays were successfully created.'
    else 
      @essay = Essay.new(essay_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @essay.save
          format.html { redirect_to @essay, notice: 'Essay was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @essay }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @essay.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
 end

# this is a private method
def break_up_batch(params, batch_id)
  essay_data = []
  # create a seperate essay for each grouped essay
  local_batch = File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp').to_s + "temppdf.pdf" , 'wb') do |f|
    f.binmode
    f.write HTTParty.get(Batch.find(batch_id).document.url).parsed_response
    f.path
  end

  params["essay"].split("~").each do |data|
    data = data.split(" ")
    hypdf_url = HyPDF.pdfextract(
        local_batch,
        first_page: data[1].to_i, 
        last_page: data[2].to_i,
        bucket: 'essay101',
        public: true

    )
      object = {student_name: data[0], batch_id: batch_id, url: hypdf_url[:url]}
      essay_data << object 
  end

  essay_data.each {|essay| Essay.create(essay)}
  File.delete(local_batch) 
end
```

I can't get the file to show up on Heroku, and I'm checking with `heroku run bash` and `ls tmp`.  So when the method is run, a blank file is uploaded to S3. I've written some jQuery to populate a hidden field which is why there's the funky splitting in the middle of the code.

Comment: The Heroku toolbelt command `heroku run bash` creates a new deployment of your application, so you will not see any files created via your rails app.  There is no sharing of filespace between Heroku apps, hence the recommended use of S3 buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using the `File` class wasn't the right way to go about it.  But using `Tempfile` works!

```
def break_up_batch(params, batch_id, current_user)
      essay_data = []
      # create a seperate essay for each grouped essay
      tempfile = Tempfile.new(['temppdf', '.pdf'], Rails.root.join('tmp'))
      tempfile.binmode
      tempfile.write HTTParty.get(Batch.find(batch_id).document.url).parsed_response
      tempfile.close
      save_path = tempfile.path

      params["essay"].split("~").each do |data|
        data = data.split(" ")
        hypdf_url = HyPDF.pdfextract(
            save_path,
            first_page: data[1].to_i, 
            last_page: data[2].to_i,
            bucket: 'essay101',
            public: true

        )
          object = {student_name: data[0], batch_id: batch_id, url: hypdf_url[:url]}
          essay_data << object 
      end
      essay_data.each do |essay| 
        saved_essay = Essay.create(essay)
        saved_essay.update_attributes(:company_id => current_user.company_id) if current_user.company_id
      end
      tempfile.unlink
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of Heroku's ephemeral filesystem, I'd highly recommend getting that file off your filesystem as fast as possible. Perhaps using the following:

1. User uploads to S3 (preferably direct: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails)
2. Kick off a background worker to fetch the file and do the processing necessary in-memory
3. If the user needs to be informed when the file is properly processed, set a "status" field in your DB and allow the front-end app to poll the web server for updates.  Show "Processing" to the user until the background worker changes its status.

This method also allows your web process to respond quickly without tying up resources, and potentially triggering an H12 (request timeout) error.